# What is the safest method of receiving payment for expensive items being sold on Gumtree?

Tags: united-kingdom, money-transfer, online-payment, electronic-payment

I intend to try to sell a laptop on Gumtree. Since this is my first time selling something online,  my knowledge of this is near zero.

I've researched the safest ways to sell items  on Gumtree and I've decided that I'll ask the buyer to come over, inspect the item,  and upon approval of its condition,  close the deal. The problem  I see  is the method of receiving payment.  Since I intend to sell the laptop for 800+, cash is not an option.

I thought that I'd ask for payment to be made through Paypal  but then I  remembered some of its irritating policies and the buyer's ability to ask for a refund.

After that, I thought that I'd just give the buyer the sort code and account number to my bank account and ask for the money to be transferred. This is the only option I feel like I have left. However, the buyer will also known my address so I'm not sure if it's safe for me to disclose this much information.

Is there a safe, foolproof method of making the sale and receiving the payment?

Comment: Why is cash not an option? If you’re worried about theft, just agree to meet at your bank and deposit the money straight away.

Comment: *"I intend to sell the laptop for 800+; so cash is not an option"* A couple weeks ago I bought a motorcyle for $7000 *cash*. I went to my bank and got 70 $100 bills and handed to the guy. He handed me a clear title and bill-of-sale. Safe for me, safe for him, relatively easy transaction.

Comment: Venmo is an option. Cash is fine, $800 isn't absurd.

Comment: @Rocky does Venmo work outside the US?

Comment: I've never used Gumtree. Do they have an FAQ or any help material that describes how transactions are typically carried out? Have you done any research on available options, other than cash and PayPal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's almost entirely safe to give out your sort code and account number. You already do this if you ever write a cheque, for example.

There is a small risk that someone could set up a fraudulent direct debit in your name. But those can only be to organisations that accept direct debits so there's not much motive to do it, and you'd be able to reverse it as soon as you notice.

It's highly unlikely that someone could use your address + account details to get any other access to your bank account. If they did it would probably be negligence on the part of the bank.

The only difficulty with a bank transfer is that it's not guaranteed to arrive immediately, so if you're trying to do the transaction in person it could be a bit tricky. The sender would also need to be able to trigger the payment while at your house, e.g. from their phone.

In most cases payments do arrive immediately (so called "faster payments"), but you'd still be reliant on your online account view updating quickly enough to be able to see that it had arrived.

You might also be able to use ["Paym"](https://paym.co.uk/faqs/) for this. Once you've registered a bank account to receive money, the sender just needs your mobile number. However I'm not sure if it solves the problem of being able to verify the payment immediately. According to [their FAQ](https://paym.co.uk/faqs/), payments can take up to two hours but most are received immediately.

Comment: Paym is usually limited to £250 per day.

Comment: Paym uses Faster Payments "under the hood" so would be no better (or worse) regarding verification. Regarding the limit: "_You can send up to £250 a day, although you may be offered a higher daily limit by your bank or building society_" so the sender _may_ have a higher limit, or _may_ be able to ask for one, depending on their bank.

Comment: @TripeHound Does it provide faster confirmation, e.g. via SMS?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I don't know; never used it. It _can't_ provide faster payment than Faster Payments, because it _uses_ Faster Payments (if that sentence is not too confusing!). Whether it _could_ text the recipient when the money is _received_ (as opposed to when it was _sent_) would depend on whether FP has an "is completed" trigger. But if I was waiting for a payment to confirm (FP or PayM) I'd probably just have my banking app open and refresh periodically).

Comment: "sort code and account number" - Isn't the UK still part of SEPA (Single European Payment Area) and using IBAN's?

Comment: @MSalters The UK doesn't use the Euro and has never been part of SEPA.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam: You're confusing SEPA and the Eurozone; I know the UK is outside the Eurozone. SEPA isn't even restricted to the European Union, Norway and Switzerland also participate.

Comment: @MSalters I guess it might apply if you are making a Euro payment from or within the UK, but as we don't use the Euro routinely, it's not particularly relevant to our day to day financial life. I've never heard of it being relevant for non-Euro payments and its own webpage also says it's about the Euro.

Comment: @MSalters BACS was never part of SEPA (although it did, for a time, allow Euro payments between Euro-denominated UK accounts), and I'm pretty sure Faster Payments isn't either. However, the UK is (at least for now) in SEPA, and many "Payment Service Providers" participate in SEPA ([see here](https://ctmfile.com/story/what-happens-to-uk-sepa-payments-after-brexit)).

Comment: @MSalters The OP pretty clearly wants to be paid in GBP not EUR.  Account transfers in GBP are still done exclusively with sort code and account number.  (This is a shame, as an IBAN has a checksum which most UK bank account numbers don't have.)

Comment: @MartinBonner: You are probably thinking of a _SEPA bank transfer_, which indeed is always in EUR. But my point was that since the UK is part of SEPA, UK banks must support IBAN for all accounts and all transfers, even those in GBP. As a service they may offer a transparent conversion of account numbers to IBAN, but they can't refuse IBAN's

Comment: @MSalters regardless, it doesn't seem at all relevant. Everyone in the UK uses sort code+account number for GBP payments, not an IBAN. IBANs typically just encode the bank name+sort code+account number anyway, so aren't any more secure from the point of view of leaking account details, even if you choose to make everyone's life more difficult by trying to use them.

Comment: @MSalters They certainly can, and do, refuse IBANs.  My bank (Nationwide) has no facility to enter the IBAN on an account transfer.

Comment: @MartinBonner The _account numbers_ themselves don't have a checksum, but in combination with the _sort-code_ there are various [_modulus checking rules_](https://www.vocalink.com/customer-support/modulus-checking/) that can be applied. Unfortunately, because they arrived late, there are a little "messy". Separately, there is a list (EISCD) of all valid sort-codes.

Answer (score 5):

Cash *is* an option.  It's less common than in Europe, but 40 £20 notes are not that difficult to count or keep secure.  If you are worried about security, you also need to worry about the "purchaser" just running off with the laptop without even pretending to pay.